# AngularJS - Getting "Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string" when testing a specific controller

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to make some unit tests for my AngularJS app. I have made several of tests suites already, all of them working. However, when testing a certain `controller` I get the following error:

`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string`

It seems its origin is in injecting the dependencies. Here's the `beforeEach` code:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('mapInteractions');
    inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$q_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $q = _$q_;
    }); //<-------- IT BLAMES THIS EXPRESSION
    inject(function(_userProgressService_,
                     _mapMarkersService_,
                     _PointAPlaceController_) {
        //custom services and controllers
        userProgressService = _userProgressService_;
        mapMarkersService = _mapMarkersService_;
        PointAPlaceController = _PointAPlaceController_;
    }); //if I remove the previous inject, it blames this one
    //...
}
```

I was first using [BardJS's inject method](https://github.com/wardbell/bardjs#inject), since it was working with every other suite, but then I tried, as you see, the original functions, and the error persisted.

It is really weird because I am testing another controller in the exact same way but everything is alright with it.

Can you detect something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your mock service or controller definition is returning a string instead of a function.

So the problem is likely in the service definition, not in the `inject` statement - it's just failing when trying to inject the invalid service.

Check if any of your mock services are returning a string as a test value - Angular might be invoking that service instance as a provider and then incorrectly treating the string as the service definition.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... Are saying that I should check in my controller/service code or my controller/service test code? Because for the test, I need only to call `inject` with native services, like `$controller`, and it fails.  
I think I understand your concern, though... I've looked into the error more deeply, by going to [its page](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string) and it seems there is something undefined somewhere...

Comment: I think the error is in the definition of one of the services in your `mapInteractions` module.

Comment: You were right! I was declaring some `module.run()` expressions wrongly, when defining some routes. Every time the module was ran, it would throw an exception. Shame that it was not more verbose.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out :)